# Why is it not possible to represent some of the dates in nanoseconds?

Tags: go

I wanted to convert a date into nanoseconds since unix epoch.But it has the limitation that it has undefined behavior for dates before 1678 or after 2262. What is the reason for that?

Comment: That's the limit of int64

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/arrays.datetime.html#datetime-units Frame challenge, *when* do you need to represent a historical time before computers even exist in nanosecond accuracy?

Comment: `2**64` nanoseconds is just under 600 years, which means you can represent dates +/- ~300 years relative to 1970.

Comment: In addition to what others have said, yes, it could be of course possible to implement `time.Duration` as a compilcated type which would, say, be able to switch to something like `math/big.Int` in edge cases to have virtually unlimited magnitude, but that would make the type complicated and slow, so there was a clear tradeoff, and the devs decided to make it simple. If you need to work with bigger magnitudes, write code to do that or look for a ready-made 3rd-party package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to answer the question:

((2^64) / (10^9))  / (60 * 60 *24 * 365.25) ~= 584.5 years

1678 + 584 = 2262

So yes, the date range chosen is because that is the range of an int64.

Since 584 / 2 = 292 and 1678 + 292 = 1970, I suspect that 0 (the old epoch date: 1970/01/01) is the middle the new range. That would make sense as it means it is possible to change precision just by multiplying / dividing the integer value by powers of 10